# Does a SQL Server Computed Column require "persistence" in order for it to be indexed efficiently?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, calculated-columns

Does a SQL Server Computed Column require "persistence" in order for it to be indexed efficiently?

It's a Name and a LoweredName (computed) column combination. So I don't believe it deals with the precision stuff mentioned in a MSDN article.

Comment: A non-persisted computed column *cannot* be indexed... so "Yes" (or it *won't work* at all). And a persisted computed column must also be a deterministic computed column ... which all makes sense in the end, considering that indices need to be updated (and thus track the source value[s]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Contrary to what Mitch has stated, you don't need a column to be persisted for an index to be created (what the MSDN article states is that, if the computed column is *not deterministic*, then it has to be marked persisted before it can be considered for inclusion in an index.</strike>

As to the original question, I'd expect the index efficiency to be as good as for any other column - what metric are we using for the efficiency? I certainly wouldn't expect it to take up more space. There would be some computation overhead during INSERT/UPDATE, but you'd have that whether or not the column was marked as persisted.

There shouldn't be any difference when it comes to querying via the index - the index structure itself would be constructed the same whether this was a real column, a persisted computed column, or an unpersisted computed column.

(Hopefully final edit) - there may be a small performance hit if you're *retrieving* the computed column, and the computation itself is expensive, when compared with e.g. the network overhead, or other I/O costs. But in the case of converting to lower case, I'd not expect to be able to notice it.

Comment: Metric - performance improvements. It's a Name and a LoweredName (computed) column combination.

Comment: So if I query the computed column (varchar type) for some value, will having it "persisted" make the query go any faster? Or does the index computation not depend on this persistence?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hmm, interesting. I've never had luck without without persistance. I should look into it later. Down-vote removed.

Answer (score 1):

No. But there are certain conditions that must be met in order to create an index on a computed column: [BOL - Creating Indexes on Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)

Comment: +1 For the link. Note to self: `varchar(max)` is not indexable, computed or otherwise :-/