# SQL Server : how to reduce a column width with minimum downtime

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with over 20 million rows. I want to reduce the width of a column from `nvarchar(100)` to `nvarchar(50)` with minimum downtime. Azure SQL premium 1 SKU takes an hour to do it using the alter table command.

An option I can think of is to create a new column and copy the data over in batches (say 100k). Finally take an exclusive lock, copy the new rows that may have appeared and then rename the columns.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why? 'NVARCHAR' will take the space needed, some bytes overhead... If the data living in this column is not bigger than 50, it won't have much effect... If there are longer strings, you will truncate them.... If you just want to ensure, that data is not longer than 50 easiest was to add a `CHECK` constraint...

Comment: I need to create a composite index which exceeds the key length so I need to change the width.

Comment: Hmm, I do not know your table, but such a big index with 20 million rows doesn't sound to pretty... Space doesn't matter - obviously - so you might just add a persisted computed column and use this in your index...

Comment: [According to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2175352/5089204) it was not even necessary to define a *persistant* computed column. No extra-space needed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alter the table as an online operation:

```
alter table t1 alter column c1 varchar(50) with (online=on)
```

Comment: This works.... alter table took over 1 hour to complete but I was able to insert to the table in the meantime.